# IMO 1979 problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

The question is
$$\text{If }\, p, \ q\in \mathbb{N}, \;1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14-\dotsb-\frac{1}{1318}+\frac{1}{1319}=\frac{p}{q}.\qquad \text{Prove that } 1979\mid p.$$

So my solution went like this:

> $$S=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14-\dotsb-\frac{1}{1318}+\frac{1}{1319}\Rightarrow S=\sum_{k=1}^{1319}\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{659}\frac{1}{2k}=\sum_{k=660}^{1319}\frac{1}{k}$$
> Now this is equivalent to finding the sum of the roots of the equation $$\left(x-\frac{1}{660}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{661}\right)\dots \left(x-\frac{1}{1319}\right)=0$$.
>
> Rewriting this equation, we get $(660x-1)(661x-1)\dotsc(1319x-1)=0$ (we can discard the $\displaystyle \frac{1319!}{659!}$ since $1979$ is a prime). Calculating the sum of the roots, we get the required value to be equal to $(1320+659)\times 330$ which is obviously divisible by $1979$ (again discarding the coeffecient of $x^{660}$).

Now my question is:
Using the same method of converting the problem into finding the sum of roots of a polynomial, we get from the original equation something like this: $$(x-1)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\dots \left(x-\frac{1}{1319}\right)=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)(2x+1)\dotsc(1319x-1)=0$$

So, the sum of roots would be $-1+2-3+4-\dotsc+1318-1319=-660$ But this is not divisible by $1979$.
Why does the former solution work while the latter doesn't? Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Note: I know that the question can be solved by some other methods. Please only explain my given doubts and don't instead give another solution

---

I realised my mistake after some hours of pondering over it.

(In the 1st equation) To get the required sum I would need to take calculate $\displaystyle -\frac{\text{coeffecient of }x^{659}\,}{\text{coeffecient of }x^{660}}$. However what I've done is calculate this:  $\displaystyle -\frac{\text{ coeffecient of }x}{\text{coeffecient of }x^{660}}$ which is actually equal to $\text{sum of roots taken }659 \text{ at a time} $. It was just a coincidence that the value I calculated was divisible by $1979$.

The correct way, indeed, would be through the link supplied [above](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln791.html)

Comment: How is the sum of the roots $(1320+659)\cdot 330$ or $-660$?

Comment: The first formula should have a negative sign for $1/4$, rigth?

Comment: I believe that what user117913 doing is finding the coefficient of the second term in the polynomial, and using the reasoning that that coefficient must be the negative of the sum of the roots multiplied by the leading coefficient. So what is being calculated is the product of the sum of roots and the leading coefficient, and since the leading coefficient isn't divisible by 1979, the sum of roots must be.

Comment: @GlenO But that second term is way bigger. It is the sum of $>600$ positive integers, each of which is at least $\frac{1318!}{659!}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - yeah, I just realised I made a mistake. The calculation is for the second-last term, not the second term. I have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: On review, I believe that user117913 is mistakenly adding the values rather than their inverses in the expansion - that is, $\frac{1319!}{659!}\sum_{n=660}^{1319} n$ rather than $\frac{1319!}{659!}\sum_{n=660}^{1319} \frac1n$, and this is the source of the problem. (of course, the correct, latter form is useless, as it simply reverts to the original expression again)

Comment: Possible solution at http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080620170208AAgADWB

Comment: http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln791.html

Comment: The IMO question is a great question. I remember my maths teacher showing it to me when I was $16$. Full marks for thinking about it and giving it a go. Getting into it yourself you get a whole lot more than when someone shows you "the easy way to solve it". So much of mathematics looks easy when you know how to do it.

Comment: I did this at the time, and scored $0$ despite winning a medal overall.  This Q1 was the [poorest answered question that year](https://www.imo-official.org/year_statistics.aspx?year=1979).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution in the comments, typed out as an answer.

The trick is to separate out the negative terms:

$$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots - \frac{1}{1318}  + \frac{1}{1319}$$
$$= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}   + \frac{1}{1319} - 2 \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}  + \cdots + \frac{1}{1318} \right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{660} + \frac{1}{661} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1319}.$$

and to notice that $660 + 1319 = 1979$. Combine terms in pairs from the outside:

$$\frac{1}{660} + \frac{1}{1319} = \frac{1979}{660 \cdot 1319}$$
$$\frac{1}{661} + \frac{1}{1318} = \frac{1979}{661 \cdot 1318}$$
$$\cdots  =\cdots$$

and so on.

There are an even number of terms, so this gives us a sum of terms in the form $\frac{1979}{m}$, with m not divisible by $1979$ (since $1979$ is prime and so does not divide any product of smaller numbers).

Hence the sum of the terms gives a rational number with denominator not divisible by $1979$. **Q.E.D**