# Let $\frac{a}{b} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac13 - \frac14 + ... - \frac{1}{1318} + \frac{1}{1319}$. Show that $1979 | a$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $\frac{a}{b} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac13 - \frac14 + ... - \frac{1}{1318} + \frac{1}{1319}$. Show that $1979  | a$. Given that , $a$ and $b$ are coprimes.

I tried to compute in pairs , but I don’t know how to do next.

Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think, you forgot to mention that $a$ and $b$ are coprimes.

Comment: Ah , yes. My mistake. Sry

Comment: This [has been asked previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634779/imo-1979-problem). But that one has no answer, so …

Comment: https://prase.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln791.html

Comment: It is not necessary to assume $a,b$ are coprime, since if the fraction is not in lowest terms $a$ will be an integer multiple of the numerator in lowest terms.

Comment: @DanielFischer I answered the original question, so when it gets an upvote, everyone should now be able to mark this question as a duplicate.